# validate math equation with empty brackets

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

I need to validate an equation, actually i have bracket validation but that don't validate if the brackets are empty only if brackets are balanced.

For example 
`2 + 5 + (3 * {1 – 2}) = 4` return true, but `1 + ()` also return true and i need to return false.

This is my code

```
function mathFormulaValidator(string) {
    "use strict";

    let formulaSP = string.replace(/ /g, ""),
        arr = [],
        valid = true;

    for (let i = 0; i < formulaSP.length; i++) {
        let char = formulaSP.charAt(i);
        switch (char) {
            case '(':
                arr.push(1);
                break;
            case ')':
                if (arr.pop() != 1) {
                    valid = false;
                }
                break;
            case '[':
                arr.push(2);
                break;
            case ']':
                if (arr.pop() != 2) {
                    valid = false;
                }
                break;
            case '{':
                arr.push(3);
                break;
            case '}':
                if (arr.pop() != 3) {
                    valid = false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                console.error(char);
                break;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

How can validate if the brackets are empty?? any ideas?

Comment: Try to parse it into a syntax tree (I guess you need to do that anyway), then it'll be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
string.match(/\(\)|{}|\[\]/) == null
```

This will return `true` if there are no empty (), {} or []

If there are any of those present, it will return `false`.

For example:

```
"[]".match(/\(\)|{}|\[\]/) == null
false

"{(}".match(/\(\)|{}|\[\]/) == null
true

"2 + 5 + (3 * {1 – 2}) = 4".match(/\(\)|{}|\[\]/) == null
true

"1 + ()".match(/\(\)|{}|\[\]/) == null
false
```

**Edit:**
Bergi is right, use it on `formulaSP` after stripping all spaces. Another limitation: it will return `true` for `"(-)"`, `"[+*/-]"` or similar.

Comment: Don't call it on `string` but rather on `formularSP`, as otherwise `"( )"` would be considered valid.